# Can I change the ID of a newly added row in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with `inlineNav` so that users can edit/add/delete rows locally and then submit all changes to the server when they are finished.  I'd like to be able to add multiple new rows to the grid locally, but due to other requirements, I need the newly added rows to have unique IDs rather than the default `new_row`.  Also, I can't use an ajax call to persist new rows immediately on add due to foreign key constraints.  I've attempted the following, but the ID value doesn't change:

```
<input type="hidden" id="newRowIndex" />

$("#thisGrid").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#thisGridPager', {
    edit: false,
    addtext: "Add",
    save: false,
    cancel: false,
    addParams: {
        position: 'last',
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true,
            oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                var newRowIndex = $("#newRowIndex").val();
                if (!newRowIndex)
                    newRowIndex = 1;
                $("#thisGrid").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'id', rowid + "_" + newRowIndex, '', '');
                newRowIndex++;
                $("#newRowIndex").val(newRowIndex);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I would simply like to set the newly added row's ID to `new_row_1`, incrementing the index for each newly added row.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

**Solution**

In addition to Dean's answer, I discovered that it doesn't work doing it in the `oneditfunc` of `addRowParams`.  I found that using jqGrid's [`afterInsertRow`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) event works:

```
afterInsertRow: function (rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
    if (rowid == 'new_row') {
        var newRowIndex = $("#newRowIndex").val();
        if(!newRowIndex)
            newRowIndex = 1;
        var newRowId = rowid + "_" + newRowIndex;
        $("#new_row").attr('id', newRowId);
        newRowIndex++;
        $("#newRowIndex").val(newRowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having issues making this work.  After dynamically changing the id after insert row, it doesn't allow me to immediately edit.  I'm using inline Add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the new row's id use:

```
 $("#new_row").attr('id',newId);
```

Referencing this question:  [Can I change the primary ID of a row in JQGrid without reloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923209/can-i-change-the-primary-id-of-a-row-in-jqgrid-without-reloading)